# How to use an interface on an empty object which gets populated at a later stage

Tags: typescript

I'm not really sure how to describe this.

But I want to define an empty object which I want to populate with data. Now on forehand I know what I want the object ultimately should look like:

```js
interface BodyInterface {
  name: string;
  lastName: string;
}
```

Some data is coming from a form submit, which looks like this:

```js
// data is formdata which looks like:
// name: "foo"
// lastName: "bar"
```

Now to add that into an object what I want to use later:

```js
const body = {}; // <- how do I use the BodyInterface on this body

someArray.forEach(({ name, value }) => {
  body[name] = data.get(name).value as string;
});
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rohan Agarwal will work, but important to note that Typescript will no longer warn you of missing properties.

A version of this is to use a Partial.

```
const body:BodyInterface  = Partial<BodyInterface>;
```

It's similar, typescript will typecheck all the properties, also not warn you of missing ones but now you have a type that actually represents that knowledge.

It's not easy to convert this to a non-partial version of BodyInterface though.

In my pre-typescript and early typescript code I would also often gradually build up objects before returning them from my functions. I found that if I want to work *with* typescript and get the most value, it's better to stop this practice altogether. Build up your individual properties in variables instead, and as a very last step build the entire `BodyInterface` all at once.

This requires changing habits, but you will get the most value out of what Typescript can do for you.

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps a bit bold, but may I ask for an example of how you'd build that object?

Comment: @Remi I basically end with something like: `const body:BodyInterface = { thisProperty, theOtherOne, ...AllTheOtherProperties }` as the last step, or `return { thisProperty, etc }`

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using as:

```
const body:BodyInterface  = {} as BodyInterface;
```

Comment: Worth noting that you will lose some typing by doing this. Typescript won't know if you missed a property.